Windows 11 doesn't save WebDAV credential as Network Drive after reboot
What it says on the can: I have a NextCloud remote instance I'd like to map as a Network Drive.
I create the drive, with credential and everything, checking "save credentials" and "connect at login" and it works as expected.
But after a reboot the network drive is not connected and when I try to connect it manually it asks me credentials.
Any ideas?
